How to remove account of this Lego?
Unknowingly, I created this account thinking this is discussion forum about logo deigning but this came to be another discussion forum of whose I have no idea at all. So, it will be great if someone cane tell how to remove this account.
And if possible please tell me something about Lego.

@jncraton Can you help me?

A good starting place for info on LEGO would be: http://aboutus.lego.com/
If you want to delete your account, go to https://bricks.stackexchange.com/contact and let them know what you need.

Thanks dude for the response.

You've got a 404 page there...

As I commented on your main question, I'll get one of the StackExchange team to remove your LEGO Answers account.
LEGO Answers is a member of the Stack Exchange network, where users can ask and answer questions on various topics. As you've noticed, we're not discussion sites, instead focusing on questions that have clear, quality answers.
I imagine that you'd like your other network accounts left alone (as you have some Reputation over on Ask Ubuntu).
Hopefully you'll come back to us when you have a question we can help you with.
In terms of discussion forums, you could start on the official LEGO Site:

Create and Share - has galleries and message boards for you to share your MOCs.
Creator - has regular building competitions.


zhaph Hey, are you taking this personal? After knowing what is this all about from @gev, I decided to stay on this and frankly my dear, I give damn to reputation. I am here to learn new things not earn reputation. Anyways, thanks for your concern. No need of your help. :)

Hi Habi, no I wasn't taking it personally - sorry if I came across that way, but it's always sad to see people go. I'll send another email to the community team asking them not to remove this account then - glad you're sticking around :)

Zhalph, are you from the Lego? You look very concerned regarding this. I was just tring to be clear on these stuff. I  not only liked the concept of Lego, I just loved it. So, I've decided to stay here.

No, I'm not from LEGO, just a user who helps look after this site and wants people to be happy ;) Just to be clear, this isn't an official LEGO site, just another fan supported and maintained one. As I said, I'm happy you're staying, and I look forward to us being able to help each other :)
